# Why aren't PHP files used for (custom) CSS and JS?

Tags: php, javascript, css

**Why don't people make** `.php` **files for their** `CSS` **and** `JavaScript` **files?**

Adding `<?php header("Content-type: text/javascript; charset: UTF-8"); ?>` to the file makes it readable by browsers, and you can do the same thing to css files by setting the `Content-type` property to `text/css`.

It lets you use all the variables of PHP and methods into the other languages. Letting you, as an example, change the theme main colors depending on user preferences in css, or preloading data that your javascript can use on document load.

Are there bad sides of using this technique?

Comment: The primary bad part is that it means the files can't be cached by the browser, which is a serious performance issue.

Comment: What makes you think they don't?  It isn't that common, but isn't unheard of either.

Comment: @Pointy You can't add cache headers?

Comment: `header("Cache-Control: value here");` can be added to the file too.

Comment: It's possible to make them cached but it does require a bit of fiddling as the built-in assumption is that PHP will be used for dynamic content.

Comment: I worked on this site, where people could create their own site/color themes using jQuery color picker and stuff. The end result was a dynamic php file which defined the css and used javascript to bind apply to html elements. So yeah, people do use that, maybe not that commonly

Comment: I do this all the time. Well, not *all* the time but I regularly embed little bits and pieces of PHP in CSS, it makes it very easy to have user-controlled colour schemes for one thing. I have also been known to put PHP in JS source files to populate them with database results. It is a technique that should be used sparingly though - you need to think very carefully about your caching setup for one thing. Also if you use sessions and you don't fully understand how they work you can screw up you page load times badly.

Comment: I would at least say that in the cases where you are going to use this, use an `.htaccess` re-write to point `dynamic.js` to `dynamic.js.php` and use proper js and cache control headers

Comment: @stevether, There is no reason for the rewriting.  I agree about using the correct cache headers.

Comment: @stevether well yes but then what's the point?  If you're going to let the browser cache the files, then you're not going to be able to process them server-side before each page is loaded. If that's the case, why do it at all?

Comment: @Pointy I do it so I can create slightly more dynamic CSS rules.  For a simple example, rather than specifying widths for a couple divs and manually figuring out what the last one should be to fill the remainder of its parent, I have a line of PHP do the subtraction for me.  Intent is much more obvious, and a change in one place will cascade into the others.  And caching it is fine because it's not something that'll change often.

Comment: @Izkata well that should be something done in a "build" phase and not in the production deployment of the CSS file. I do that stuff too, but the "dynamic" part is resolved before the files are deployed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

People do it more often than you think. You just don't get to see it, because usually this technique is used in combination with URL rewriting, which means the browser can't tell the difference between a statically-served .css file and a dynamic stylesheet generated by a PHP script.

However, there are a few strong reasons *not* to do it:

- In a default configuration, Apache treats PHP script output as 'subject to change at any given time', and sets appropriate headers to prevent caching (otherwise, dynamic content wouldn't really work). This, however, means that the browser won't cache your CSS and javascript, which is bad - they'll be reloaded over the network for *every single page load*. If you have a few hundred page loads per second, this stuff absolutely matters, and even if you don't, the page's responsivity suffers considerably.
- CSS and Javascript, once deployed, rarely changes, and reasons to make it dynamic are really rare.
- Running a PHP script (even if it's just to start up the interpreter) is more expensive than just serving a static file, so you should avoid it unless absolutely necessary.
- It's pretty damn hard to make sure the Javascript you output is correct and secure; escaping dynamic values for Javascript isn't as trivial as you'd think, and if those values are user-supplied, you are asking for trouble.

And there are a few alternatives that are easier to set up:

- Write a few stylesheets and select the right one dynamically.
- Make stylesheet rules based on class names, and set those dynamically in your HTML.
- For javascript, define the dynamic parts inside the parent document before including the static script. The most typical scenario is setting a few global variables inside the document and referencing them in the static script.
- Compile dynamic scripts into static files as part of the build / deployment process. This way, you get the comfort of PHP inside your CSS, but you still get to serve static files.

If you want to use PHP to generate CSS dynamically after all:

- Override the caching headers to allow browsers and proxies to cache them. You can even set the cache expiration to 'never', and add a bogus query string parameter (e.g. `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://example.com/stylesheet.css?dummy=121748283923">`) and change it whenever the script changes: browsers will interpret this as a different URL and skip the cached version.
- Set up URL rewriting so that the script's URL has a .css extension: some browsers (IE) are notorious for getting the MIME type wrong under some circumstances when the extension doesn't match, despite correct `Content-Type` headers.

Comment: In my testing, I've found that adding a query string will prevent IE caching the file at all, as it assumes it's dynamic. A solid reference to prove or disprove me would be welcome.

Comment: In fact, it's not even just IE - see my comment elsewhere on the page.

Answer (score 10):

Some do, the better thing to do is generate your JS/CSS scripts in PHP and cache them to a file.

If you serve all of your CSS/JS files using PHP, then you have to invoke PHP more which incurs more overhead (cpu and memory) which is unnecessary when serving static files.  Better to just let the web server (Apache/nginx/lighttpd/iis etc) do their job and serve those files for you without the need for PHP.

Comment: Exactly. If they seldom change, there's a benefit to being able to generate and store them when they do, but little benefit to dynamically building them on every request (browser caching aside).

Comment: I don't have specifics but it will vary based on how PHP is invoked (module, CGI) and with what modules PHP is compiled with (the more modules, the more baseline memory is used).  In most cases the extra overhead is probably small, but it can add up greatly if have a huge number of concurrent users.  Basically you end up invoking PHP unnecessarily to generate the same content over and over when it could be served statically.

Comment: This isn't really an argument against using PHP though, just being sure to use it right. Any content with a high reload vs modification ratio should be properly cached, whether it's an asset, an HTML page, or pure data.

Comment: @IMSoP Good point, PHP is great at what it does, but when it comes to serving static content PHP is unnecessary (at least beyond generating the initial file and then caching it as appropriate).

Comment: "the better thing to do is generate your JS/CSS scripts in PHP and cache them to a file." - or use [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)

Answer (score 4):

Running the PHP engine does not have a zero cost, in either time or CPU. And since CSS and JavaScript files usually rarely change, having them run through the engine to do absolutely nothing is pointless; better to let the browser cache them when appropriate instead.

Comment: Not to mention static files can be hosted at CDNs

Comment: @tdammers: But you still have to invoke PHP every time, even if just to get the 304.

Comment: I think tdammers meant that the files which don't change can be static, CDN'd, etc, but those parts which do change (e.g. customisable styles in a CMS) can be served via PHP. I agree that getting caching arranged so that there is no PHP invocation is tricky, although it's not completely impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Here’s one method I’ve used: The HTML page contains a reference to `/path/12345.stylesheet.css`. That file does not exist. So `.htaccess` routes the request to `/path/index.php`. That file (a) does a database request, (b) creates the CSS, (c) **saves the file for next time**, (d) serves the CSS to the browser. That means that the very next time there’s a request for `/path/12345.stylesheet.css`, there actually is a physical static file there to be served by Apache as normal.

Oh, and whenever the styles rules are edited (a) the static file is deleted, and (b) the reference ID is changed, so that the HTML page will in future contain a reference to `/path/10995.stylesheet.css`, or whatever. (Actually, I use a UNIX timestamp.)

I use a similar method to create image thumbnails: create the file on first request, and save a static file in the same place for future requests. I’ve never had occasion to do the same for javascript, but there’s no fundamental reason why not.

This also means that I don’t need to worry about caching headers in PHP: only the *first* invocation of each CSS file (or image thumbnail) goes through PHP, and if that is served with anti-caching headers, that’s no great problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you might have to dynamically create javascript or styles.

the issue is webservers are optimized to serve static content.  Dynamically generating content with php can be a huge perforamce hit because it needs to be generated on each request.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bad idea, or all that uncommon, but there are disadvantages. Caching is an important consideration - you need to let browsers cache when the content is the same, but refresh when it will vary (e.g. when someone else logs in). Any query string will immediately stop some browsers caching, so you'll need some rewrite rules as well as HTTP headers.

Any processing that takes noticeable time, or requires a lock on something (e.g. session_start) will hold up the browser while it waits for the asset.

Finally, and quite importantly, mixing languages can make editing code harder - syntax highlighting and structure browsers may not cope, and overlapping syntax can lead to ugly things like multiple backslash escapes.

In javascript, it can be useful to convert some PHP data into (JSON) variables, and then proceed with static JS code. There is also a performance benefit to concatening multiple JS files ago the browser downloads them all in one go.

For CSS, there are specific languages such as Less which are more suited to the purpose. Using LessPHP (http://leafo.net/lessphp/) you can easily initialize a Less template with variables and callbacks from your PHP script.

Comment: A query string **does not** stop the browser from caching.  That's up to the cache directives given by the served resource.

Comment: As mentioned elsewhere on this page, that's my experience testing with IE; it appears to interpret pages with a query string as dynamic. IIRC, it sends an If-Modified-Since, but handling that for dynamically generated content is hardly trivial.

Comment: I can reproduce this consistently with latest Firefox (14.0.1). Go to http://rwec.co.uk/x/caching/cache-test-dummy.html and open an HTTP debugger such as Firebug or Fiddler, and click the "self" link repeatedly. The URL with the query string is checked repeatedly using If-Modified-Since. These are all static files, so the server responds with a 304. If that was a PHP script, it would be running on every page load.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is often used as a processor to generate dynamic content. It takes time to process a page and then send it. For the sake of efficiency (both for the server and time spent in programming) dynamic JS or CSS files are *only* created if there isn't a possible way for the static file to successfully accomplish its intended goal.

I recommend only doing this if absolutely you require the assistance of a dynamic, database driven processor.

Answer (score 0):

The bad sides: plenty, but to name just a few:

- It'll be dead slow: constructing custom stylesheets for each request puts a huge load on the server, not something you want.
- Designers create CSS files, programmers shouldn't (in some cases shouldn't be allowed to). It's not their job/their speciality.
- Mixing JS and PHP is, IMHO, one of the greatest mistakes on can make. With jQuery being a very popular lib, using the `$` sign, it might be a huge source for bugs and syntax errors. Besides that: JS is a completely different language than virtually any other programming language. Very few people know how to get the most out of it, and letting PHP developers write vast JS scripts often ends in tears. 
  JavaScript is a functional OO (*prototypal*) language. People who don't full understand these crucial differences write bad code as a result. I know, because I've written tons of terrible JS code.
- Why would you want to do this, actually? PHP allows you to change all element's classes while generating the page, just make sure the classes have corresponding style rules in your css files and the colours will change as you want them, without having to send various files, messing with headers and all the headaches that comes with this practice

If you want more reasons why you shouldn't do this, I can think of at least another few dozens. 
That said: I can only think of 1 reason why you would think of doing this: it makes issues caused by client-side cached scripts less of an issue. Not that it should be an issue in the first place, but hey...

Comment: Don't agree on the 'programmers shouldn't create CSS files'. Designers should create designs; it's up to programmers / CSS specialists to bake those into stylesheets.

Comment: Also disagree on the 'PHP programmers can't write JS' part. Not everyone is a one trick pony; some of us can work comfortably in half a dozen languages and have no problem switching between them. And JS isn't *that* different - it's basically half of Scheme in Java camouflage. If you want 'unlike any other language', try Haskell. Or Malbolge.

Comment: Counter points: 1. Caching negates speed concerns once done and PHP isn't "dead slow" 2. The argument is for a CSS file (with extra hints/variables), not necessarily BL 3. PHP is being argued for as use of a "template" here 4. Why not? That is what the poster is asking :)

Comment: @tdammers: yes, it's up to the front-end developers to do that. But the people I know of and have worked with, who have an expertise in webdesign and usability, wouldn't be too happy to spend their days writing their stylesheets in PHP. They'd tell you to go F yourself, and give you a list of classes and sprites, and tell you which class will make your error message appear `light magenta` and which will turn out `deel-blue-purple`. Saves both sides a lot of time (developers not having to explain how their objects works, designers not having to wade their way through messy code)

Comment: @tdammers: look, I put things rather sharply because I feel the OP is considering something I regard as bad practice. Some PHP developers can write good JS code. But weather you like it or not, a lot of people still don't know that JS follows the functional paradigm. I've seen a lot of JS that just oozes abuse and failure to understand this, absurd constructions to implement classical inheritance, event handlers that are anon. functions that do nothing more than call a predefined function etc... Yes, I know what JS is, and it is the first and only functional _mainstream_ language

Comment: @pst: if you have a decent sized webapp, the variations you can have in the styles will be more than just 10 files to cache... if you have 1 well written file, PHP can be left do do what it's good at: processing requests and generating pages. link to a stylesheet and that's it. Why generate more that 1 file? That wíll slow the app down. my point is why go to the trouble (and time) of extra development if you can just change your html attributes (classes, id's etc...) rather then a tailor made CSS or CSS with variable contents, making it _way_ harder to debug/restyle

Comment: The classic example for CSS is allowing customization of a colourscheme through a CMS or similar.