# Unwanted CSS within Source Code

Tags: css, wordpress

In my source, I have the following code:

```
<style>
/*Twenty Twelve fixes and other theme fixes and styles :( */

.flex-caption {
     background: #000;   
     -ms filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#4C000000,endColorstr=#4C000000);
     filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#4C000000,endColorstr=#4C000000); 
     zoom: 1;
 }

/*...*/
</style>
```

This is not within my personal CSS file and i have no idea where this is being pulled from.

I am linking to my external CSS file as per Wordpress Codex to include a stylesheet as per below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" />
```

What do I need to do to remove this CSS?

***EDIT****

this has now been fixed.

Comment: Why don't you just search the files on disk for this string of text?  That will tell you where it's coming from pretty easily.  You can probably limit the search to just the /wp-content folder.

Comment: Inspecting it w/ Chrome or using the IE dev tools should help you track down the culprit...

Comment: Hi Rikon, unfortunately im not very knowledgable on those tools, i will see if i can find it elsewhere, thanks

Comment: Hi Ek0nomik, as i said this is not within my CSS at all, so all i can think of is that its coming from some dodgy source that i dont know about :S

Comment: Kirsty both those are valid ways for find and solve your problem. You can't just dismiss them like that and expect help.

Comment: looking at the source one can see it is pulled like that from the server, not manipulated with JS. Can you post your `header.php` code?

Comment: Is Wordpress include external CSS files that way by default? They should read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853063/why-arent-php-files-used-for-custom-css-and-js

Comment: @KirstyHarris: note that you can respond to a specific commenter by using the "@" sign followed by their user name.

Comment: Hi Codeguy007, as i said im not entirely up on Debugging as im a novice at this, i dont expect someone to sort my code for me as well, im going to look into a debugger and see if i can figure it out, theres only 2 things that i know of that could create that :)

Comment: I don't even see the undesired CSS in the page source when I visit the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured what was generating this and removed. It was a plugin, and it was one that I'm not using.

NextGEN gallery plug in generates this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you started with either WordPress's TwentyTwelve theme, or another theme which inherited from it and made changes from there. If you look at `/wp-content/themes/head.php` I think you may find the offending styles in there.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not in your CSS it's probably in header.php

Go to Appearance > Editor > Header (header.php)